# Updating table based on zip code table

Tags: sql, sql-server, zip

I am looking for a way to update a table containing `city, state, zip, and county` by using a different table containing all the necessary information.

To put it simply, I have a table (let's call it `Table1`) that lists all the `cities, states, and counties` by `zip code` (or whatever order you want to put those in).  I want to update a different table (call it `Table2`), specifically `city, state, and county`, using the `zip code` from Table1.

EDIT: MS SQL Server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First, it helps when asking questions about SQL to specify in the tags which DB you're using, as answers can vary based on that info. Second, since there are multiple ZIP codes for some cities, how would you take that into consideration? The clearer you can make your question, the better your chances are of getting an answer. :=)

Comment: Further, zip codes aren't constrained to political subdivisions: a given zip code can span (and does, depending on the carrier routes contained within the zip code) city, county and state (theoretically) boundaries. Zip codes can even be discontiguous.

Comment: The CSV I found had only unique zip codes (so no duplicates) and as far as the city/state/county not being 100% accurate I'm not too worried about.  This is mostly for the purpose of updating NULL values (and county values of USA) to something meaningful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE A
SET A.City = B.City
FROM Table2 AS A
INNER JOIN Table1 B
ON A.PostalCode = B.PostalCode
WHERE A.City IS NULL --Or Some Other Criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE Table2
SET t2.City = t1.City,
t2.state= t1.state,
t2.county= t1.county

FROM Table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON t2.zipcode= t1.zipcode
```